# What is wrong with this code of file handling in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am new to c++ and specifically file handling. 
I made this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
    public:
    char s;
    int age;
};
int main (void)
{
    student a;
    a.s = 'a';
    a.age = 1;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("a1.txt",ios::app);
    myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a),sizeof(student));
    return 0;
}
```

When I opened the file `a1.txt`, it had the character a correctly in there, but for the integer it had some weird encoding and a message that if you continue to edit this file, it will be corrupted. Can't I write an object to a file containing an integer and a character or a string as well?

Comment: If you're looking for formatted output, use `operator<<`.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: If you expect the file to have "a1", you should know you're ignoring padding first of all, and an `int` is typically four bytes, which means four characters in the file.

Comment: this was just a small example. Actually, I want to write an object containing `strings , chars, integers ( total 10 in number )`, will I have to `a.string1, a.string2, a.age1, a.rollnum1...` for each one of them or is there a better way?

Comment: the "weird encoding" will be the bytes that make up the integer's representation. The "message that if you continue to edit" is something that your editor is doing, not your C++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define your own << operator that handles your custom type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    char s;
    int age;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const student &o) 
{
    output << o.s << "  " << o.age;
    return output;
}

int main (void)
{
    student a;
    a.s = 'a';
    a.age = 1;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("a1.txt",ofstream::app);
    ofstream << a;
    return 0;
}
```

When you called `myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a),sizeof(student));` it was not converting your struct to a human-readable string then writing it to file. In reality, it was **interpreting** the memory of your struct as a series of characters then writing it to file.

Comment: this was just a small example. Actually, I want to write an object containing `strings , chars, integers ( total 10 in number )`, will I have to `a.string1, a.string2, a.age1, a.rollnum1...` for each one of them in the additional function that you made or is there a better way?

Comment: Not really. You don't have to define an operator << but you will have to define some type of method that accesses all of your custom struct / class members to insert them into a file. There is no way for ostream to iterate over all the members of some arbitrary struct and stringify them. At least as far as I know. (There could be some type traits templating magic that might be able to)

Comment: @chris yeah, I made more than a few copy-pasta errors in an effort to beat others to the punch.

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar, You're right. There's no standard way to iterate over members. That will change if one of these proposals for compile time reflection gets accepted.

Comment: @chris Is that proposed for c++ 14 or c++ 17?

Comment: @user3769571 Change `ofstream << a;` to `ofstream << a << endl;`

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar, C++14 is already out. There were several proposals for C++14, but none of them got in. I'm half-thinking one will be accepted for C++17 after they fine-tune the proposals to incorporate the feedback from the committee.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing the binary representation of `student` into the file. The character will come out as expected; but the `int` will be the bytes used to represent the value, not a readable number.

If you want the output to be formatted as readable text, use formatted output:

```
myfile << a.s << ' ' << a.age << '\n';
```

For convenience, you could overload the operator for your class:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, student const & a) {
    return os << a.s << ' ' << a.age;
}

myfile << a << '\n';
```

For more complex structures, you might consider the [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library. Or you might do what I tend to do, with tuples instead of plain structures, and variadic templates to read and write them, but that might be rather more fiddly than you'd like.

Comment: this was just a small example. Actually, I want to write an object containing `strings , chars, integers ( total 10 in number )`, will I have to `a.string1, a.string2, a.age1, a.rollnum1...` for each one of them or is there a better way?

Comment: @user3769571, You might try letting [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) take care of it.

Comment: Does Boost.Serialization guarantee human-readability or just serialization to raw bytes?

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar: It allows arbitrary "archive" types, including text-based ones.

Answer (score 0):

You actually did write the int to the file, but not readable (123 => '1' '2' '3')
but the 4 (or 8) byte of that int. Your program can read the value back too,
the only probem is that we humans can´t read that form well.

Concering Strings:Just writing the whole struct will probably fail
(depending on the exact type of the string variable etc.), because the
"string" often stores only a pointer in the struct (which points to some
memory elsewhere, and this other memory isn´t written automatically to the file)
To be safe, write each variable of the struct explicitely (and handle different
var type appropiately) instead of writing them all together.

This way, things like different variable ordering and struct padding
can´t cause problems too. Other pitfalls to remember are different int
sizes and endianess on different computers... serialization isn´t trivial.